# using substring and foreach in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

```
    Dictionary<int, string> names= GetNames().Where(x =>  
x.Value.StartsWith("test") | x.Value.StartsWith(" " + "test")).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

The values from the getNames() method are something like this:

John Testing

Test Travis

Test Metsaoy

Using the above line of code I'm getting only the two last entries, but I want also the 1st one because the 2nd string starts with "test".

So, I need to modify the above where statement. I tried something like this:

```
.Where(x =>  
    foreach ( xx in x.Value.Split(' ') ) { if ( xx.StartsWith("text") ) true; })
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't you want to use `Contains()`?

Comment: No, because for example 'GGGtest Johhny' I do not want to consider as an OK example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var parser = new Regex(@"\bTest", RegexOptions.Compiled);
GetNames().Where(x => parser.IsMatch(x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value)
```

Comment: Better yet, create a single Regex object and use it in `Where`. This avoids parsing the same pattern each time

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you're right. I changed the sample.

Comment: Another nice thing - Regex is thread safe so you could even use PLINQ (ie `GetNames().AsParallel().`) to search a large array in parallel

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I know but that was not the question and maybe AsParallel() willl change the order of items. I don't know weather this matters or not.

Comment: @Verarind: using your above example, I get only those entries starting with "test"... For example the entry: "Mary test" will not be counted

Comment: @FlorinM. Yes it's clear. Your lastname starts with a lower case. Your sample code doesn't return anything because all _Test_-names will start with an upper case. If you want to ignore casing use `new Regex(@"\bTest", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);` or change the pattern to `@"\b[Tt]est"`.

Comment: @FlorinM. I don't know what you're doing but in my case it works: [Code Sample](http://ideone.com/jjD1VN)

Comment: @Verarind Yep, I tried also something like this for a string: " Test bef" and it works ( having a space char at the beginning of the 1st string )

Answer (score 4):

```
var res = GetNames().Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Split()
                                 .Any(s => s.StartsWith("Test") || s.StartsWith("test")));
```

Optionally instead of `StartsWith` you can use [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Any` lambda.

Comment: nice. You only forget space in `Split()`

Comment: Instead of splitting the string and generating a lot of temprorary strings, it's faster and more efficient to use a Regex. Temporary strings can cause a *lot* of trouble when processing even a moderate amount of text

Comment: @teovankot find a large file and try it then. It's a well known issue in text processing. A regex match returns the offsets of the matches, not the string itself, so no temporary strings, no GC pressure and no memory bloat. The new Diagnostic Tool window in VS2015 can show this in a *very dramatic* way

Comment: @teovankot - space is the default separator for `Split` - see msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can use `public IEnumerable<string> GetNames() { for (var i = 0; i < 1 << 20; ++i) { yield return "John Testing"; yield return "Test Travis"; yield return "Test Metsaoy"; } }` for performance testing :-)

Comment: @Verarind first, what is this code supposed to do? Second, I have no need to test what I've found and fixed in production, processing log files of over a hundred thousand lines: simply using a Regular expression instead of splitting improved speed and reduced memory by an order of magnitude. That allowed me to parallelize the job with Dataflow and process multiple files in parallel without worrying about RAM - or the GC cost

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
x.Value.StartsWith("test") || x.Value.Contains(" test")
```

You'll have to use it in your query like this:

```
var names= GetNames()
    .Where(x => x.Value.StartsWith("test") || x.Value.Contains(" test"))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @w.b the `Contains` has a blank space `' '` at the left, to allow matching only words that start with `test` and not words that have `test` in the middle, like `somewordwithtest`.